# URL Encoding in XSL in DataPower

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

How can I achieve URL encoding of a specific element value from an XML message? From the below input I need to do URL encode for only the value of URL tag.

**Sample Input:**

```
<response>
```

?googleid={xxxx}&ShowToolbar={@current}&lo_id=-1&page=/google.co/imp/vlc&addBreadCrumb=N

**Required Output:**

```
<response>
```

%3Fgoogleid%3D%7Bxxxx%7D%26ShowToolbar%3D%7B%40current%7D%26lo_id%3D-1%26page%3D%2Fgoogle.co%2Fimp%2Fvlc%26addBreadCrumb%3DN

Thanks in advance for your help. Cheers!

Comment: Have you searched for the answer to your question? (No, you haven't. Why not?)

Comment: I tried searching it, but the answers were not really related to my one.

Comment: The duplicate question was the first Google hit for me, other helpful links were among the first ten Google hits. It's completely impossible that you came up empty after even a few minutes of searching.

Comment: Instead of using XSL function, I used dp:encode function to achieve this successfully.

Comment: Good you found something that works. Tip for your next XSLT question: Mention the exact type and version of your XSLT processor and any extensions that are available (like in your case, IBM WebSphere DataPower). For the people who answer questions it's very important to know what you are working with.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for your suggestion.